# Can I downgrade the target SDK from Beta?

Tags: java, android, xml, google-play, publish

> **TL;DR: I need to downgrade the target SDK, but I am unable to because that would "hurt existing users", *which shouldn't be a problem*
>   because the only existing user in my CLOSED beta testing, was ME!**

[image]

The reason for my downgrade in the target SDK happens to do with the way my app is handling permissions, and it would be most effective if I had it in SDK level 22.

*How can I combat this? I really need to publish my app in the SDK 22!*

---

> Isn't the whole point of beta testing to test different aspects
>   of your app in order to make changes for release? Now when I'm trying
>   to make those changes for release (by changing the SDK version), google will not let
>   me.

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible; but why would you want to *downgrade* your target SDK in the first place? Have something against [Run Time Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)?

Comment: @Bryan For the nature of this current app, in this case scenario, I would prefer to not include Run Time Permissions.  Using them would, of course, have to be my last case, although I don't know why I shouldn't be able to downgrade—especially if the initial APK was uploaded ONLY to CLOSED beta testing. Isn't the whole point of beta testing to test different aspects of your app in order to make changes for release? Now when I'm trying to make those changes (changing the SDK version), google will not let me.